# reduce build time with webpack config

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js, webpack-4

I use vue.js, nuxt and webpack in my project. 
after scaling up of project build time gets more and more.
I need to know is there any config in webpack to check and build just changed components and files in the initial build?

Comment: How long it takes for you? Do you use vuetify with vuetify loader?

Comment: @Aldarund about 5 mins. no just use bootstrap

Comment: thats a lot. How large your project? How long build on your pc for empty nuxt project?

Comment: @Aldarund empty nuxt project takes 10 sec.

Comment: So your project have like thousand of pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to experiment with hardsource and cache properties.

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#hardsource

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#cache

That should make subsequent builds much faster

Comment: actually, it's good for build time but file watching and hot reloading don't work anymore. Do you have any idea about this?